# Does the Disciplined badge not show up in achievements?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, achievements-dialog

I had occasion to delete a score = 3 answer yesterday (legitimate reasons - I'd misinterpreted the question). I got the Disciplined badge, but the achievements list doesn't show it. It does show the `grep` tag bronze badge I got on U&L today, and a Good Answer badge from Meta AU three days ago.

Is this by design?

Comment: No bug, see dupe

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, it is a dupe. That post needs to mention achievements somewhere - I didn't think to search for notifications because I assumed that would be for the inbox.

Comment: Good point, I'll try to see how to edit that. Edit: done. :)